# Need list of newly added & modified existing C functions committed to SVN

Tags: svn

I used command `svn diff` with `-x -p` option. It shows the changes committed, however diff output doesn't list specific function name.

Current command and output(Added line "//Comment 2"):

```
# svn diff  -r12:13
@@ -2,7 +2,9 @@
```

Expected output:

```
@@ -2,7 +2,9 @@ void fun3()
```

How to get the list of all functions which are added and modified in mentioned committed revision?

Note: tried `svn diff` (before commit without version), still with `-x -p` option its not showing function name.